# Can't declare a variable in ArangoDB

Tags: nosql, arangodb, aql

I'm using **ArangoDB 3.4.6-1** and would like to delete vertices with AQL (as stated [here](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/examples-remove-vertex.html)) in online console.

In the first step according to the tutorial you are supposed to save your Edges into a variable. In my case the statement looks like this:

```
LET edgeKeys =  (FOR v, e, p IN 1..100 INBOUND 'Node/N3' GRAPH 'graph' RETURN e._key)
```

The `For` itself without the brackets returns the correct result:

```
[
  "E3"
]
```

Yet, running the whole statement with the brackets just throws the following error:

```
Query: AQL: syntax error, unexpected end of query string near ')' at position 1:83 (while parsing)
```

I tried using a comparable command with other graphs or other returned values and objects, but always get the same error.

So far I wasn't able to find a proper solution online. The tutorial provides the following example code (copied 1:1):

```
LET edgeKeys = (FOR v, e IN 1..1 ANY 'persons/eve' GRAPH 'knows_graph' RETURN e._key)
```

And I'm getting exactly the same error, it's not even able to check the collections.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only defining a variable with `LET` is not a valid AQL statement.

From the [AQL Syntax documentation](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/fundamentals-syntax.html#query-types):

> An AQL query must either return a result (indicated by usage of the
>   RETURN keyword) or execute a data-modification operation (indicated by
>   usage of one of the keywords INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE, REMOVE or
>   UPSERT). The AQL parser will return an error if it detects more than
>   one data-modification operation in the same query or if it cannot
>   figure out if the query is meant to be a data retrieval or a
>   modification operation.

Using the full AQL block that is stated in the tutorial the execution works as expected since the query is executing a data-modification with `REMOVE` in this case. Just a `RETURN` operation inside the `LET` variable declaration is not sufficient to run an AQL query. When removing the `LET` operation the query works as well since in this case the AQL query directly returns the result.

Complete AQL query:

```
LET edgeKeys = (FOR v, e IN 1..1 ANY 'persons/eve' GRAPH 'knows_graph' RETURN e._key)
LET r = (FOR key IN edgeKeys REMOVE key IN knows) 
REMOVE 'eve' IN persons
```

An additional RETURN also makes the query work:

```
LET edgeKeys = (FOR v, e IN 1..1 ANY 'persons/eve' GRAPH 'knows_graph' RETURN e._key)
RETURN edgeKeys
```